# Windows XP midi port

Tags: windows-xp, midi, midi-virtual-keyboard

I am trying to connect my Casio 810IN keyboard to windows XP. Installed the driver that came with the keyboard, also made settings so that it is sending data to the midi port.

But, no sound coming from my laptop speakers (running windows XP). I am a noob in this. How to setup so that the speakers output the sound data from the MIDI port?

thanks

JP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MIDI port doesn't send "sound" data, it send "event" data (eg Keys that you press and similar). You need a program which can interpret these events and produce sounds from them.

Comment: Ah yes, I meant event data. Can you recommend any free program? Thanks.

Comment: Found a full free program! Proteus X Composer. Works great. Has some cool realistic built in tones :)